# Child classes, and variabled inheritance

Tags: c#

I started making some small games with my friend in C#'s XNA game library, and I made a `Player` class, which is too large to post, but has a little protected variable:

```
protected int moveSpeed = 3; (which affects how fast Player can move)
```

I have a class child, `Fighter`, as the game will be based on different battle types, and I would like Fighter to inherit the properties (including variables) of Player. For example: `moveSpeed`, but whenever I try to assign Fighter a specific value for moveSpeed, it won't let me openly declare `moveSpeed = 2;`, for example and says: moveSpeed is a `FIELD`, but used as a `TYPE`. Does `C#` not have direct variable access, or does that only apply to functions/methods.

PS: I have never messed around with inheritance in C#, only java. Any help is appreciated, and thank you.

Comment: Please show us the complete line at which this error is being reported.

Comment: You can make a setter for the field, or you can use your constructor for the child class to override the base class constructor.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Are you sure that you haven't defined another variable in child class by the same name ?

Comment: That line (moveSpeed = 2;) needs to be inside a method or constructor. You usually get this error when you put such code directly in the class body.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to re-declare the variable, you just want to change it's value.  You can best do that in the constructor:

```
public class SomeTypeOfPlayer : Player
{
  //protected int moveSpeed = 2; DON'T DO THIS! It would be 
  //re-defining it, not setting the existing field.

  public SomeTypeOfPlayer()
  {
    moveSpeed = 2;  //Do this
  }
}
```

Comment: But you still can't change value of `moveSpeed` later on, which I think is what the question is really asking. As an aside - suffixing classes with `Extension` is misleading as it looks like you intend to use it for extension methods.

Comment: @Yuck Changed the class name.  Not sure what you mean by not being able to change movespeed though, it's not readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on description your code *should* look like this:

```
  public class Player
  {
       public double MoveSpeed {get;set}
  }

  public class Fighter : Player 
  {
  }
```

declare `MoveSpeed` like a auto-property of base class (avoid declaring fields like `public` and access the directly, but use properties for this)

Comment: Doesn't look like it's ever exposed publicly, just used internally within the class.  A field is appropriate for that.

Comment: Why not just `protected double MoveSpeed { get; set; }`? Or even `public double MoveSpeed { get; protected set; }`?

Comment: @Servy: yes, but according to post he tries to access that field from the object of the child class, which is not a good design. Infact I wrote, do not define public fields, but define public properties.

Comment: @Yuck: could be also that, matter of design. I *have no idea* what is application of Op's, so just provide with a solution. After it can be shaped to fit *exact* needs of his application. I hope noone just copy/paste the code from responces here.

Comment: @Tigran so you don't think one should ever define a protected property?  You keep using the word 'public'.  Nothing here is public, just private or protected.

Comment: @Servy: I've already responded on this. It's a matter of design. I just provide one o a few possible solutions.

Comment: you seem to be equating public with protected.  I'm saying you can't do that.  They are different, and affect design differently.

Comment: @Servy: I know that. I just don't know what are design goals of the OP. Based on *that* goals you decide how to architect accessibility of your class inheritance architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You declared MoveSpeed as a `protected` field. So you can access this in the derived classes of Player. But you can not access it outside that. If you have a `Property` you can access it outside the derived class also. When you create an auto implmented property, A Getter and Setter method is being created behind the scene to set and retrieve the value of the backing up fields ( created by CLR).

Assuming your class structure is like this

```
public class Player
{
 public int MoveSpeed { set;get;}    
}

public class Fighter : Player
{
 public int FigherTypeId { set;get;}
}
```

You should be able to set the Player MoveSpeed like this

```
Fighter objFighter=new Fighter();
objFighter.MoveSpeed=35;
```

If you want to keep the field as `Protected`, you can do that and Set the Property value in child class contructor

```
public class Player
{
 protected int MoveSpeed =3;

}
public class Fighter : Player
{
    public int FigherTypeId { set; get; }

    public Fighter(int _moveSpeed)
    {
        MoveSpeed = _moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

and Create child class object like this

```
Fighter objFighter = new Fighter(44);
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/491031.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I try to assign Fighter a specific value for moveSpeed, it won't let me openly declare moveSpeed = 2;, for example and says: moveSpeed is a FIELD, but used as a TYPE

Normally this happens when you write an assignment statement (like `moveSpeed = 2;`) right inside a class, while it should be inside a method or constructor.

The error message is somewhat confusing, but it makes sense: statements inside a class normally start with a type (`int bla = 123;`), while in this case the first word is a name of variable (`moveSpeed`).

Just move `moveSpeed = 2;` to your constructor (or a method, or a property) and that's gonna fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, it sounds to me like you are needing **moveSpeed** to be a constant (i.e. not able to alter at runtime)?  I say this because it sounds like you want a base **Player** which has a speed of 2, but want to then create a derived class of **Fighter** which is able to move at a faster speed, but these speeds are fixed for each of the types of player.

You cannot have a virtual const, but you can have a virtual property which only has a getter:

```
public virtual class Player
{
    protected virtual int MoveSpeed { get { return 2; } }
}

public class Fighter : Player
{
    protected override int MoveSpeed { get { return 3; } }
}
```